# identify error in if statement

Tags: bash, scripting

Here is the complete code..

What I'm trying to do is this - >

I'm trying to find the average of the values in the second column of the files . 
If the file has 2.54 in its name, I want to find averages from files called file_2.54_even.xls and file_2.54_odd.xls . If the fiename does not have 2.54 in its name, then simply find the average of file. For example: file_1.60.xls

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in pmb_mpi tau xhpl mpi_tile_io fftw ; do

    for f in 2.54 1.60 800 ;do

 if [ ${f}  = "2.54" ]
 then 
     echo ${file}_${f}_even_v1.xls
     awk 'sum+=$2 ;END {print "Average = " , $sum/NR > ${file}_${f}_avrg.xls }' ${file}_${f}_even_v1.xls
     echo ${file}_${f}_odd_v1.xls
     awk 'sum+=$2  ;END {print "Average = " , $sum/NR > ${file}_${f}_avrg.xls }' ${file}_${f}_odd_v1.xls
 else
     echo ${file}_${f}_v1.xls 
     awk 'sum+=$2 ;END {print "Average = " , $sum/NR > ${file}_${f}_avrg.xls }' ${file}_{f}_v1.xls
 fi
     done
done
```

Comment: Please post all of the code and details of your platform; that sample works fine in bash, both Cygwin and Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: It works for me in both of those, plus zsh, ksh and dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `awk` command is inside single quotes, the shell variables `file` and `f` will not be expanded. That's why you're getting the `awk` errors.

I would use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in pmb_mpi tau xhpl mpi_tile_io fftw ; do
  for f in 2.54 1.60 800 ; do
    if [[ ${f} = "2.54" ]] ; then
      flist=${file}_${f}_even_v1.xls ${file}_${f}_odd_v1.xls
    else
      flist=${file}_${f}_v1.xls
    fi
    cat ${flist} | awk '
      s+=$2;
      END {print "Average = ",$s/NR}
      ' >${file}_${f}_avrg.xls
    # Or use awk '...' ${flist} >${file}_${f}_avrg.xls
    # if you're overly concerned about efficiency of processes.
  done
done
```

That will simply set `flist` to either both files or one file, depending on whether `f` is `2.54` or not, then push that list of files through a single `awk` script.

Comment: Useless use of `cat` - `awk` will accept multiple files via your `$flist` variable as an argument: `awk '...' ${flist} > ${file}...`

Comment: I know it's useless in this case but that has little to do with the question - you may just as well complain about the indentation style or multi-line awk script :-) I tend to do all my pipelines the same (starting with cat) since not all commands allow the sort of expressiveness you're talking about.

Comment: PAxdiablo.. u have hit the nail on the head . Congrats !

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem may be you're comparing integers and strings.

Try

```
if [ $(f) -eq 2.54 ]
```

Although not seeing the full code I can't see what line the error is on.

Edit: Trying it in cygwin I get no error however.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just move the redirection?

```
 awk 'sum+=$2 ;END {print "Average = " , sum/NR }' ${file}_${f}_even_v1.xls > ${file}_${f}_avrg.xls
```