# printing variable inside awk

Tags: scripting, awk, printing

In this script , I want awk to print the variables `$file`, `$f`, `$order` and `sum/NR` (all in a single row)

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in pmb_mpi tau xhpl mpi_tile_io fftw ; do
    for f in 2.54 1.60 800 ;do
    if [ ${f} = 2.54 ]
    then 
        for order in even odd ; do
#       echo ${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls >> P-state-summary.xls
        awk '{sum+=$2} END {print ${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls, sum/NR}' ${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls >> P-state-summary.xls
        done
    else
#       echo ${file}_${f}_v1.xls >>  P-state-summary.xls
        awk '{sum+=$2} END {print  ${file}_${f}_v1.xls , sum/NR}' ${file}_${f}_v1.xls >>  P-state-summary.xls
    fi
    done
done
```

Colud anyone of you kindly help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
echo -n "${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls " >> P-state-summary.xls
# or printf "${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls " >> P-state-summary.xls
awk '{sum+=$2} END {print sum/NR}' "${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls" | 
    tee "${file}_${f}_avrg.xls" >> P-state-summary.xls
```

Using `echo -n` or `printf` without a "\n" will output the text without a newline so the output of the `awk` command will follow it on the same line. I added a space as a separator, but you could use anything.

Using `tee` will allow you to write your output to the individual files and the summary file using only one `awk` invocation per input (order) file.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` doesn't go out and get shell variables for you, you have to pass them in as `awk` variables:

```
pax> export x=XX
pax> export y=YY
pax> awk 'BEGIN{print x "_" y}'
_
pax> awk -vx=$x -v y=$y 'BEGIN{print x "_" y}'
XX_YY
```

There is another way of doing it by using double quotes instead of single quotes (so that `bash` substitutes the values before `awk` sees them), but then you have to start escaping `$` symbols and all sorts of other things in your `awk` command:

```
pax> awk "BEGIN {print \"${x}_${y}\"}"
XX_YY
```

I prefer to use explicit variable creation.

By the way, there's another solution to your previous related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823166/identify-error-in-if-statement/1825559#1825559) which should work.