# How to print variable inside awk

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

I want the awk to interpret the variable as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

file=tau
f=2.54
order=even

awk '{sum+=$2}; END {print '${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls', sum/NR}'
${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls >> safe/P-state-summary.xls
```

I want the desired output as follows -

```
tau_2.54_even_v1.xls   sum/NR
```

Can anybody help me out with this ?

Comment: You already received an answer to this question from **paxdiablo** here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825509/printing-variable-inside-awk/1825622#1825622 - use awk's variable passing feature

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825509/printing-variable-inside-awk

Comment: using the -v option : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=tau
f=2.54
order=even

awk "{sum+=\$2}; END {print \"${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls\", sum/NR}" \
  ${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls >> safe/P-state-summary.xls
```

Answer (score 18):

First, you need to `export` environment variables if you want them to be passed in the environment of a child process like `awk`.

Second, you can use `ENVIRON["name"]` to get an environment variable in `awk`. So the following works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

export file=tau
export f=2.54
export order=even

awk '{sum+=$2}; END {print ENVIRON["file"] "_" ENVIRON["f"] "_" ENVIRON["order"] "_v1.xls", sum/NR}'
```

Answer (score 12):

Don't forget that you can set "AWK variables" on commandline

```
awk -v FOO=bar '...<AWK code that uses the AWK variable FOO>...'
```

Comment: ie:

###
    
    date | awk -v USER=$USER '{ print USER ": "  $0 }'

###

    rzr: Sat Nov 30 18:25:24 CET 2013

###

Answer (score 0):

Well I used a mixture of the above solutions and got it working with this

```
printf "\n${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls  " >> Safe/P-state-summary.xls
awk '{sum+=$3}; END  {print sum/NR}' ${file}_${f}_${order}_v1.xls >> Safe/P-state-summary.xls
```