# How do I use shell variables in an awk script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I found some ways to pass external shell variables to an `awk` script, but I'm confused about `'` and `"`.

First, I tried with a shell script:

```
$ v=123test
$ echo $v
123test
$ echo "$v"
123test
```

Then tried awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "'$v'"}'
$ 123test
$ awk 'BEGIN{print '"$v"'}'
$ 123
```

Why is the difference?

Lastly I tried this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print " '$v' "}'
$  123test
$ awk 'BEGIN{print ' "$v" '}'
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{print
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I'm confused about this.

Comment: I like the -v as shown below, but this is really a great exercise in thinking about how to protect things from the shell. Working through this, my first cut use backslashes on spaces and dollar signs. Needless to say the examples here were well worth my time.

Comment: Related: [Difference between single and double quotes in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44445852/6862601).

Comment: If your awk search needs **regular expression**, you can't put `/var/`. Instead, use tilde: `awk -v var="$var" '$0 ~ var'`

Comment: @NoamManos, why is it not possible to use a variable inside a reg expression delimited by "//" ? I've been reading a lot of info (and superb awk manual, BTW) for a few hours and I am already a bit overwhelmed, so apologies if this is easy to find out

Comment: @Kiteloopdesign because the `/.../` delimiters mean a **literal** regexp so nothing expands inside them. If you don't want a literal regexp then don't use `/.../` delimiters, use `"..."` and/or variables for a **dynamic** regexp.

Answer (score 655, accepted):

> #Getting shell variables into `awk`
> may be done in several ways. Some are better than others. This should cover most of them.  If you have a comment, please leave below.                                                                                    v1.5

---

### Using `-v`  (The best way, most portable)

Use the `-v` option: (P.S. use a space after `-v` or it will be less portable. E.g., `awk -v var=` not `awk -vvar=`)

```
variable="line one\nline two"
awk -v var="$variable" 'BEGIN {print var}'
line one
line two
```

This should be compatible with most `awk`, and the variable is available in the `BEGIN` block as well:

If you have multiple variables:

```
awk -v a="$var1" -v b="$var2" 'BEGIN {print a,b}'
```

**Warning**.  As Ed Morton writes, escape sequences will be interpreted so `\t` becomes a real `tab` and not `\t` if that is what you search for. Can be solved by using `ENVIRON[]` or access it via `ARGV[]`

**PS** If you have vertical bar or other regexp meta characters as separator like `|?(` etc, they must be double escaped. Example 3 vertical bars `|||` becomes `-F'\\|\\|\\|'`. You can also use `-F"[|][|][|]"`.

> Example on getting data from a program/function inn to `awk` (here date is used)

```
awk -v time="$(date +"%F %H:%M" -d '-1 minute')" 'BEGIN {print time}'
```

> Example of testing the contents of a shell variable as a regexp:

```
awk -v var="$variable" '$0 ~ var{print "found it"}'
```

---

### Variable after code block

Here we get the variable after the `awk` code. This will work fine as long as you do not need the variable in the `BEGIN` block:

```
variable="line one\nline two"
echo "input data" | awk '{print var}' var="${variable}"
or
awk '{print var}' var="${variable}" file
```

- Adding multiple variables:

`awk '{print a,b,$0}' a="$var1" b="$var2" file`

- In this way we can also set different Field Separator `FS` for each file.

`awk 'some code' FS=',' file1.txt FS=';' file2.ext`

- Variable after the code block will not work for the `BEGIN` block:

`echo "input data" | awk 'BEGIN {print var}' var="${variable}"`

---

### Here-string

Variable can also be added to `awk` using a [here-string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) from shells that support them (including Bash):

```
awk '{print $0}' <<< "$variable"
test
```

This is the same as:

```
printf '%s' "$variable" | awk '{print $0}'
```

P.S. this treats the variable as a file input.

---

### `ENVIRON` input

As TrueY writes, you can use the `ENVIRON` to print **Environment Variables**.
Setting a variable before running AWK, you can print it out like this:

```
export X=MyVar
awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["X"],ENVIRON["SHELL"]}'
MyVar /bin/bash
```

or for a non-exported variable:

```
x=MyVar
x="$x" awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["x"],ENVIRON["SHELL"]}'
MyVar /bin/bash
```

---

### `ARGV` input

As Steven Penny writes, you can use `ARGV` to get the data into awk:

```
v="my data"
awk 'BEGIN {print ARGV[1]}' "$v"
my data
```

To get the data into the code itself, not just the BEGIN:

```
v="my data"
echo "test" | awk 'BEGIN{var=ARGV[1];ARGV[1]=""} {print var, $0}' "$v"
my data test
```

---

### Variable within the code: USE WITH CAUTION

You can use a variable within the `awk` code, but it's messy and hard to read, and as `Charles Duffy` points out, this version may also be a victim of code injection.  If someone adds bad stuff to the variable, it will be executed as part of the `awk` code.

This works by extracting the variable within the code, so it becomes a part of it.

If you want to make an `awk` that changes dynamically with use of variables, you can do it this way, but DO NOT use it for normal variables.

```
variable="line one\nline two"
awk 'BEGIN {print "'"$variable"'"}'
line one
line two
```

Here is an example of code injection:

```
variable='line one\nline two" ; for (i=1;i<=1000;++i) print i"'
awk 'BEGIN {print "'"$variable"'"}'
line one
line two
1
2
3
.
.
1000
```

You can add lots of commands to `awk` this way.  Even make it crash with non valid commands.

One valid use of this approach, though, is when you want to pass a symbol to awk to be applied to some input, e.g. a simple calculator:

```
$ calc() { awk -v x="$1" -v z="$3" 'BEGIN{ print x '"$2"' z }'; }

$ calc 2.7 '+' 3.4
6.1

$ calc 2.7 '*' 3.4
9.18
```

There is no way to do that using an awk variable populated with the value of a shell variable, you NEED the shell variable to expand to become part of the text of the awk script before awk interprets it. (see comment below by Ed M.)

---

### Extra info:

#### Use of double quote

It's always good to double quote variable `"$variable"`
If not, multiple lines will be added as a long single line.

Example:

```
var="Line one
This is line two"

echo $var
Line one This is line two

echo "$var"
Line one
This is line two
```

Other errors you can get without double quote:

```
variable="line one\nline two"
awk -v var=$variable 'BEGIN {print var}'
awk: cmd. line:1: one\nline
awk: cmd. line:1:    ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: one\nline
awk: cmd. line:1:    ^ syntax error
```

And with single quote, it does not expand the value of the variable:

```
awk -v var='$variable' 'BEGIN {print var}'
$variable
```

#### More info about AWK and variables

[Read this faq](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24).

Comment: I strongly disagree that `-v` is the "best, most portable way".  `awk -v a=b cmds path1 path2` is (almost) equivalent to `awk cmds a=b path1 path2`, but there is no good way to use `-v` to emulate `awk cmds path1 a=b path2`  Defining variables in the arguments is an extremely useful technique which is equally portable and which I will argue is "better".

Comment: @WilliamPursell when you define your variables among the file names in the args list a) they aren't set in the `BEGIN` section and b) they are interleaved with the file names in `ARGV[]` and so make it harder to loop on file names, compare the current `FILENAME` to an `ARGV[]` position, e.g. to use `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` instead of `NR==FNR` to avoid empty input file issues in multi-input-file scripts. IMHO the only time to do that is when you need to change the values of variables (e.g. `FS`) between files, otherwise use `-v` or `ENVIRON[]` for the most intuitive use of variables.

Comment: Regarding `there is no good way to use -v to emulate awk cmds path1 a=b path2` - you could also claim there's no good way to use that approach to emulate `awk -v a=b cmds path1 path2`, as they just have different semantics. IMHO it's easier to emulate `awk cmds path1 a=b path2` with `awk -v a=b cmds path1 path2` than the other way around though as `a` is simply not available in the BEGIN section the first way and it's pretty easy to, in the BEGIN section, save/clear/set it between files the second way.

Answer (score 34):

It seems that the good-old `ENVIRON` [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) built-in hash is not mentioned at all. An example of its usage:

```
$ X=Solaris awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["X"], ENVIRON["TERM"]}'
Solaris rxvt
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion because it passes the data verbatim. `-v` doesn't work when the value contains backslashes.

Comment: @thatotherguy I did not know that! I thought that if I use `awk -v x='\c\d' ...` then it will be used it properly. But when `x` is printed [tag:awk] drops the famous: `awk: warning: escape sequence '\c' treated as plain 'c'` error message... Thanks!

Comment: It does work properly - properly in this context means expand escape sequences because that's how `-v` was designed to work so you can use `\t` in  the variable and have it match a literal tab in the data, for example. If that's not the behavior you want then you don't use `-v` you use `ARGV[]` or `ENVIRON[]`.

Comment: @TrueY : that's dependent on which `awk` : if you set an assignment like `__='\ABCDEF'` using single quotes at the shell level, `mawk`s (`1` or `2`) reads in as a literal backslash then the letters ( equiv to manually typing `"\\ABCDEF"` ), `nawk`s would throw away that backslash since it doesn't map to any of its predefined escaping patterns, thus `__ == "ABCDEF"`, while `gawk`s do the same as `nawk`s all while complaining very loudly about single backslash. Another annoying `gawk` caveat that still persists till today in 2024 is that it thinks `__='+++++++?'` is perfectly valid `ERE regex`

Comment: @EdMorton : I'm amazed `gawk` thinks a regex like ::::::: ::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::  `re = ".{13107181913171272345678952189232389607107, -9999999999999}"` is perfectly valid `ERE`. Even turning on linting (`-L`) didn't result in any warnings whatsoever, let alone errors, fatal or otherwise, or worse, this one : `re = "+++{13107181913171272345678952189232389607107, -9999999999999}++++++++"`, with the most amazing part being `match(re, re)` results in `RSTART == 1, RLENGTH == 62`

Comment: @EdMorton : or THIS regex ::::: ::::::::::::: :::::::::: :::::: :::::: ::::::::::: : :::::: ::::::::::: ::::: ::::::: :::::: :::::: :: :::: `(.{.,.}?)*{13107181913171272345678952189232389607107, -9999999999999}` ::: matching to itself at `RSTART == 11` and `RLENGTH == 59`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto this may warrant posting (or updating) a bug on gawk's bug place.

Comment: @OlivierDulac it's not a bug. In a regexp interval expression like `{m,n}` the values of `m` and `n` must be positive integers, if you put anything else there such as `.` or `-9999999999999` then it's simply undefined behavior, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_06. The previous ones Kpop mentioned, REs starting with `\A` , and `+`, - `A` is already a literal character and `+` is a repetition metachar meaning 1 or more of the preceding RE segment but there IS no preceding RE segment so both are simply undefined behavior. Just don't do that.

Comment: Per [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_06): `\A` - "The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped <backslash> ( '\\' ) is undefined". RE starting with `+` - "*+?{ ... Any of the following uses produce undefined results: If these characters appear first in an ERE". Interval expression without numbers `{.,.}` - "an interval expression of the format "{m}", "{m,}", or "{m,n}", ... The values of m and n are decimal integers in the range 0 <= m<= n<= {RE_DUP_MAX}". All are simply undefined behavior and so to be avoided.

Comment: @EdMorton : that's my point - undefined and unknown behavior shouldn't default to a match. They were all intentionally crafted to be waaaaaay outside of proper `ERE` specs, but they aren't all obscure either. They ARE supposed to error out, such as RE range out of bounds etc. `gawk` has a RE interval range check mechanism, but clearly these examples are slipping through. I only brought it up in light of the `python` `CVE` that got themselves seriously dinged for `DDoS` risk because of absurdly large inputs from nefarious users.

Comment: @EdMorton : as for `The values of m and n are decimal integers in the range 0 <= m<= n<= {RE_DUP_MAX}".` , you can try entering things like `e`  `pi`  or even the numeric value of `sqrt(31)` and `gawk` happily truncates them for you instead of erroring out

Answer (score 10):

You could pass in the [command-line option](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Options) `-v` with a variable name (`v`) and a value (`=`) of the environment variable (`"${v}"`):

```
% awk -vv="${v}" 'BEGIN { print v }'
123test
```

Or to make it clearer (with far fewer `v`s):

```
% environment_variable=123test
% awk -vawk_variable="${environment_variable}" 'BEGIN { print awk_variable }'
123test
```

Comment: This just reiterates part of the accepted answer but will only work in some awks due to no space between `-v` and `v=`.

Answer (score 6):

You can utilize ARGV:

```
v=123test
awk 'BEGIN {print ARGV[1]}' "$v"
```

Note that if you are going to continue into the body, you will need to adjust
ARGC:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ARGC--} {print ARGV[2], $0}' file "$v"
```

Comment: This just reiterates part of the accepted answer and YMMV with just decrementing ARGC without clearing it's slot in ARGV[].

Answer (score 1):

I just changed @Jotne's answer for "for loop".

```
for i in `seq 11 20`; do host myserver-$i | awk -v i="$i" '{print "myserver-"i" " $4}'; done
```

Comment: This merely seems to be another illustration of how to use Awk's `-v` option which was already mentioned in many of the existing answers. If you want to show how to run Awk in a loop, that's a different question really.

Answer (score 0):

I had to insert date at the beginning of the lines of a log file and it's done like below:

```
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
awk '{ print "'"$DATE"'", $0; }' /path_to_log_file/log_file.log
```

It can be redirect to another file to save

Comment: The double quote - single quote - double quote was exactly what I needed to make mine work.

Comment: This was already mentioned in the accepted answer as a method you should not use due to code injection vulnerabilities. So the information here is redundant (already described in the accepted answer), and incomplete (does not mention the problems with this method).

Answer (score -1):

### Pro Tip

It could come handy to create a function that handles this so you dont have to type everything every time. Using the selected solution we get...

```
awk_switch_columns() {
     cat < /dev/stdin | awk -v a="$1" -v b="$2" " { t = \$a; \$a = \$b; \$b = t; print; } "
}
```

And use it as...

```
echo 'a b c d' | awk_switch_columns 2 4

Output:
a d c b
```

Comment: See UUOC in https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award. Also - use single instead of double quotes around your awk script (as you always should by default) and then you won't have to escape the `$`s within it because you won't be inviting the shell to interpret it before awk sees it. It's not obvious why you put big, bold "Pro Tip" at the top of this answer, most of the other answers are better and this doesn't add any value to the accepted answer, it just uses it in one specific context.